# Spring Boot service - update one entity before updating another

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to update one entity before updating another but i am not able to figure out what is the problem with this. I do not want to instantiate new Stock, i want to update existing stock, which i get from repository - 'productInStock'.

My Service method is:

```
private final TransactionRepository transactionRepository;
private final StockRepository stockRepository;

public Transaction saveNewProduct(Transaction transaction) {
        Long productId = transaction.getProduct().getId();
        Integer newProductQuantity = transaction.getQuantity();
        Optional<Stock> productInStock = stockRepository.findByProductId(productId);
        if(productInStock.isPresent()) {
            Integer stockQuantity = stockRepository.findTotalStockQuantityByProductId(productId);
            Integer updatedProductQuantity = stockQuantity + newProductQuantity;
            productInStock.setTotalStockQuantity(updatedProductQuantity);
            stockRepository.save(stock);
        } else {
            Stock stock = new Stock();
            stock.setProduct(transaction.getProduct());
            stock.setTotalStockQuantity(transaction.getQuantity());
            stockRepository.save(stock);
        }
        return transactionRepository.save(transaction);
    }
```

An IDE says 'Cannot resolve method 'setTotalStockQuantity()' in 'Optional'

Answer (score 0):

OK, i found the decision myself!

Instead of:

```
Integer stockQuantity = stockRepository.findTotalStockQuantityByProductId(productid);
```

There should be:

```
Integer stockQuantity = productInStock.getTotalStockQuantity();
```

Now it is working!